# Is it possible to remap ‘wq’ to save and close the current buffer instead of saving and quitting in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

Vim newbie here.

When I issue the `:wq` Ex command, I would like to make it save and close just the active buffer, instead of saving it and then quitting from Vim.

Similarly, I would like to make the `:q` command to be identical to `:bd` in its effect.

Any suggestions how to implement this behavior?

Answer (score 13):

Vim allows the user to add key mappings for commands in all modes,
including the Command-line mode, so one can define the following
mappings (in one’s `.vimrc` file):

```
:cnoreabbrev wq w<bar>bd
:cnoreabbrev q bd
```

These commands instruct Vim to expand the <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>
key presses in the command line into `w|bd` and, similarly, expand
<kbd>Q</kbd> into `bd`. See `:help key-mapping` for more details.

Comment: -1. Please, don't use `cnoremap` for that! This will expand q in any command. For example `:set cscopequickfix` will expand to `:set cscopebduickfix`. Use `:cnoreabbrev` instead! See the help for that.

Comment: Your first cnoremap won't work. The line tells Vim to remap command mode wq to w, and then close the current buffer - not rebind wq to w|bd. Benoits complaints are also valid, however, you can do :cnoremap wq<cr> w<bar>bd<cr> - this will work as expected.

Comment: Sarah, no. Still `cnoreabbrev` is better because if you want to write your file as `anything ending with wq` the abbreviation will not trigger unless the filename is exactly wq.

Comment: I agree completely, though it still has to be w<bar>bd.

Comment: Also, you can emulate `:x` for buffers with `:cnoreabbrev bx up<bar>bd
`, which will write the buffer only if it's changed, and then close the buffer.

Comment: Problem with `wq` mapping is that it doesnt actually quit, but this is really an issue with concept of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Sayonara plugin](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-sayonara).

I tried the other answer but it was missing a use case.  When I close the last buffer, I want it to close Vim, like a regular `:q` command.  `:bd` will just leave you with a blank window and no buffer.

Here's the mapping, adapted from the other answer:

```
" Prevent accidental closing of all buffers when doing :wq or :q
cnoreabbrev wq w<bar>Sayonara
cnoreabbrev  q       Sayonara
```