# Quit vim when all buffers are closed after :bd

Tags: vim

I want to [remap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115841/remapping-wq-to-save-and-close-buffer-instead-of-save-and-quit) `:q` as `:bd` because I really don't want the buffer to stay around in a long-running `vim` session (where it can hold a `.swp` file conflicting with another `vim` session of the same file).

The only problem with that is `:bd` does not quit `vim` if it is the last buffer left. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you looked at [BBye](https://github.com/moll/vim-bbye)? It does state this, however, which may not satisfy your question: "Shows an empty file if you've got no other files open."

Comment: Thanks Micah. I actually don't need the fancy `BBye` features. I want `:q` to mean `:bd`, but just do `:q` (i.e. quitting `vim`) if this is the last buffer.

Comment: Try this one: http://superuser.com/questions/668528/vim-quit-if-buffer-list-is-empty/930871#930871.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
fun! s:quitiflast()
    bdelete
    let bufcnt = len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)'))
    if bufcnt < 2
        echo 'shutting everything down'
        quit
    endif
endfun

command! Bd :call s:quitiflast()

cmap q Bd
```

Comment: Plain `cmap q Bd` is a really bad idea, you won't be able to write any word containing "q" on the command line after that. See the [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_to_enter_colon_commands) for a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Two versions, one asking to save, and one quitting forcefully:

```
" Close the current buffer, quit vim if it's the last buffer
" Pass argument '!" to do so without asking to save
function! CloseBufferOrVim(force='')
  if len(filter(range(1, bufnr('$')), 'buflisted(v:val)')) == 1
    exec ("quit" . a:force)
    quit
  else
    exec ("bdelete" . a:force)
  endif
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>q :call CloseBufferOrVim()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>Q :call CloseBufferOrVim('!')<CR>
```